# Stripping commas out of PHP

Tags: php, string, str-replace, strip

I have a dynamic value that is being stored in a PHP variable. The variable holds a string of data that represents which check-boxes were clicked. It is returned like so: Option1, Option2, Option3, Option4.....

I would like to strip out the commas so it is just Option1 Option2 Option3 Option4....

My Code:

```
<?php 
    $type = the_field('type_of_work'); 
    $type = str_replace(",", "",$type);
    echo $type; 
?>
```

For some reason, the commas are still being rendered. Any idea why or how I can fix this? Just so you know, the_field('type_of_work') is a way to pull advanced custom fields from wordpress' backend, but shouldn't be relevant to this question as it is retuning a string with commas successfully. Any thoughts?

UPDATE: I am going about this a different way like so:

```
if(in_array('brand-id', get_field('type_of_work') )): 
    echo "brand-id";
endif; 

echo " ";

if(in_array('print', get_field('type_of_work') )): 
    echo "print";
endif;
```

so on....

Comment: Possible character encoding issue?

Comment: perhaps....unsure at this point

Comment: Your edit is slightly puzzling because it doesn't really explain the problem any better.  Can you perhaps provide some sample values for `$type` or `type_of_work`?

Comment: sample values (in checkboxes) would be print, web, editorial, etc. I already figured out the solution, but I can see why this is puzzling.  To understand it you need to familiarize yourself with ACF syntax: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/docs/field-types/checkbox/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is something else you are not including. The code you posted does it's job perfectly. If you still see commas then something else is playing a part here.

```
<?php 
    $type = the_field('type_of_work'); 
    $type = str_replace(",", "",$type);
    echo $type; 
?>
```

This is the prefect time to `die` so you know for sure.

```
<?php
die(str_replace(',', '',the_field('type_of_work')));
?>
```

Comment: I suppose you are right....there is something else going on. Looks like it is the wordpress custom field. but it is strange because it does return a basic string...

Comment: @xeo - don't be so dramatic :P

Answer (score 2):

Although the code you provided should work perfectly, may I suggest using this instead:

```
$type = explode(',', $type);
```

This will turn it into an array of values. It would also be a good idea to `trim()` each of the values individually.

So, instead of:

```
$item = 'Item1 Item2 Item3';
```

You would get an array of:

```
$item = array('Item1', 'Item2', 'Item3'); // Assuming each value is `trim()`ed
```

Comment: yep, not working just like all the other answers! I am going back to the drawing board here!

Comment: @JCHASE11, provide more information (exact code being used, perhaps?) and we should be able to help you better :)

Answer (score 0):

regex replace

```
preg_replace("/,/", "", $string);
```

Comment: This is basically a much less efficient version of the author's posted code.

Answer (score 0):

You could try exploding them into an array and then imploding them back out...

```
$split = "super,cali,fragilistic,expi,alidocious";
$arr = explode(",",$split);
$finalStr = implode(" ",$arr);
echo $finalStr;
```

`super cali fragilistic expi alidocious`

---

Docs for [implode](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) and [explode](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php).

Answer (score 0):

This is the trick:

```
<?php
$type = get_field('type_of_work');
$type = implode(' ', $type);
echo $type;
?>
```

Or simply:

```
<?php echo implode(' ', get_field('type_of_work')); ?>
```

because get_field ist an array.